# How should you secure a multi-tenant API with Identity Server?

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I'm struggling with the correct way to secure a multi-tenant Web API with Identity Server. Let me explain.

We have a multi-tenant Web API that serves a ASP.NET MVC application.

- Each new customer is assigned a new TenantId.
- A customer can have multiple subscriptions of the application. Its
  the same as saying that the app manages multiple databases per
  customer (that he can access from the same base URL).
- Each user belongs to a single customer (tenant) and will have access
  to all that customer's subscriptions.

The API is set in a way that every endpoint includes both the tenant id and the subscription id so it can know from which subscription/database it should get the data.:

`<server>/tentantId/subscriptionId/(...)`

Now imagine that I have another external app (say a console app), using the client credentials flow, that is trying to access some API resource "on behalf" of a customer, meaning that will use a specific tenantId/subscriptionId pair:

`<server>/1000/1/products`

Every time a call hits one of the API endpoints I need to validate that this specific client app can access that tenant/subscription.

**It would make a lot of sense if the Identity Server could perform that check automatically as part of the authorization flow.**

If we added some way for the customer to register (consent) a specific client app to access the Web API on it's subscriptions, may be we could also set the Identity Server to know that in the form of scopes or at least include that information in the claims so that we could perform the permission check by inspecting the token instead of calling an external component.

Is this even possible?
Should I try to use scopes? Claims?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: > *validate that this specific client app can access that tenant/subscription* The devs have stated explicitly that idsrv3 is [not designed for tenant-scoped clients](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/558) :(

Comment: I have exactly the same question, except for IdentityServer 4.  How did you end up handling this?

Comment: @CShark I solved this on Identity Server 4 using user claims. The user has or has not a claim stating that it can access a given tenant/subscription. There is authorization policy on the controller actions that checks that and returns Forbid if the correct claim is not present.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing when you talk about multi-tenancy. Isn't an API multi-tenant by default? The way I see it, it's a resource that can be accessed by multiple users / clients.

If I understand correctly, all you want is to access the API through the MVC app on behalf of a user. In other words: [a hybrid flow with API access](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html#refhybridquickstart).

Instead of putting the userid in the path, use the id from the `sub` claim. Which lets the API distinguish between calls on behalf of clients and calls on behalf of users.

The resource should take care of [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/). Depending on the type of authorization you can use claims. If a subscription needs to be checked then this should be done by the API, using the `sub` claim to distinguish the user.

Scopes on the other hand are meant to define the resource. With the scope "api1" I can access the Api1 resource (api). But it says nothing about authorization.

Comment: I suppose that my English resources make it more difficult to explain the whole idea. The user id is not in the path. It's the tentant/subscription that is in the path and that is because we want the user to be able to use the URL to get to a particular view in the MVC (SPA) app directly in the browser. Our MVC app uses the Hybrid flow but the question is about external applications trying to use the API directly to access data from a particular tenant/subscription by using the corresponding URL. When the request hits that URL I need to validate if the client app can access that subscription.

Comment: For external applications you use the client_credentials flow. As part of its configuration you add the tenantid as claim. The resource can then authorize the request by checking if the tenant has the requested subscription. You can still leave the tenantid in the path, but it has to be equal to the value of one of the claims. For each tenant that the client has access to you add a claim, while the path specifies the tenant/subscription.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg "Isn't an API multi-tenant by default?".  No.  Don't confuse multi-tenancy and multi-user.  Multi-tenancy may extend multi-user, but an API is not multi-tenant by default.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer provides **[Authentication as a Service](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/#authentication-as-a-service)**.

It is your apps' duty to provide the actual **Authorization**.

Comment: I understand that. The idea here is to at least use the information managed by identity server (the scopes?) to perform the authorization. Thus avoiding another call (on every access to every API endpoint) to an external source to check if that particular client has access to that tenant/subscription. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: Well you can use the scopes per client. For example - one API has a required scope 'myapi'. Then all the clients that have this scope in their allowed scopes, can access the API. Other clients will be rejected by IdentityServer. If this is what you want to achieve - this is your solution. But from what I understood, you want one client to has access to some controllers of an api, another client - to other controllers. This is what IdentityServer cannot control.

Comment: What do you think of passing on client claims to the API controllers and use that info to implement custom policies (as requirements) to validate if the client app has the right claim for each controller?

Comment: Well, for me this is what you should do, if you want to achieve your goal, but  it is also what I initially said - the client is performing the `authorization`. Go with this approach.