# Identity Server 4 - User Authentication - Confidential App - Multiple Client Secret - One Client_ID

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I've a scenario for a Third Party Client App (Mobile App - With Client Secret) to connect to the Identity Server for getting access to a Resource Server. During the user login the Client App display multiple store location for the user to sign in.

The Client App is designed to have a unique secret for each store location and one Client_ID.

When a store is selected by the end user for login - the ID Server gets a request from the client app with the Client_ID and the specific secret matching to the store location.

**The Question I've over here is, how to make the Identity Server (3 or 4) to perform the User Login based on the Store Location.**

I'm thinking of intercepting the Client_Secret to use it during the User Login to map to the correct store id by having a lookup table in place.

Is this a good approach to get this scenario worked out, or can someone shed some light with any possible suggestions to make this scenario work with the Identity Server.

The Expected flow:

1. Client App Displays the Store Location's in the Login Screen
2. User Selects the specific store location
3. User is directed to the Identity Server Authorization Endpoint and Client Validation is taken place.
4. Authorization Server Displays - User Login Screen
5. The Authorization Server authenticates the end User based on the store location. **(Need to figure out a way to achieve this)**

Answer (score 0):

If you intend the login flow to be completed within mobile app itself and not within browser client, then you will need to use `resource owner credentials` grant type, in which case, it doesn't really matter if you have one or many secrets per store as it authenticates a single client based on your scenario.

On the other hand, if you intend the login flow to be completed within browser client, then it also doesn't matter if you have many secrets or one because in that case I assume the store selection would be done within the login screen like you mentioned which would part of the auth server.

All in all, nowhere in your flow the store location seem to matter unless there is some kind linkage between user credentials and store id. If that is the case, then this is essentially a multitenancy question for Identity Server 4 for which there are discussions already open with suggestions.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2673

[How should you secure a multi-tenant API with Identity Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428568/how-should-you-secure-a-multi-tenant-api-with-identity-server)

Comment: Thanks @vidmantas-blazevicius for the reply!  The Grant Flow that's being used by the third party mobile app is Authorization Code Flow - with Client Secret.  The store selection by the user happens at the Mobile App itself and then a request is made to the authorization endpoint and the Identity Server displays the login screen. 
 For user authentication - the ID4 server looks at a custom user table that contains users from all the stores.  So based on the store selected by the user - the respective client_secret is used to hit the Authorize Endpoint.

Comment: @vishakos I still fail to see what relevance the store selection holds in your login flow. The user will ultimately have to enter his/her credentials at the login screen rendered by IdentityServer4 (from the way you described it). Which secret was used to authenticate the actual client (mobile app in this case) is irrelevant as long as the secret was one of the valid ones so the extra step to select the store sounds like a redundant step in your intended login flow.